# How can I tell SWIG to copy my source's documentation into it's generated files?

Tags: documentation, wrapper, swig

I have some C API that contains docs such as

```
 // file: my_module.h

 /**
  * My function.
  * @param x A number.
  * @return Return.
  */
extern int my_function(int x);
```

My swig file

```
%module my_module
%{
#include "my_module.h"
%}

%include "my_module.h"
```

If I generate a wrapper for python for example, I will get this python wrapper function generated

```
 # file: my_module.py

 # < I want my docs copied here
 def my_function(x):
    return _my_module.my_function(x)
```

Is there a way to tell SWIG to copy my docs to the output so that when I use the wrapper, I can see my docs in the python editor's intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out myself, but SWIG 4.0 has some support for doxygen comments:

http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Doxygen